# Не полный обзор баз из консоли mysql

Tags: mysql, cmd, denwer, веб-сервер

Работаю с консолью mysql. Потребность возникла, потому что нужно импортировать большую по размеру базу данных (Более 115 Мб). В phpMyAdmin это терпит крах, даже, когда я в php.ini меняю время жизни ожидания загрузки файлов, а также максимальный их размер. Делаю работу консоли с mysql через стандартный cmd процесс. Для этого прописал в переменных средах директорию mysql. Естественно запускаю денвер, затем из консоли вхожу в mysql. Через оболочку PhpMyAdmin у меня показывает наличие 10 баз данных, а через консоль всего две. Моей базы не видит, в которую мне нужно залить мега-данные).

Команду делаю show databases;

В чем причина? Объясните мне, пожалуйста.

Comment: Похоже на то, что под пользователем под которым подключаетесь в консоли нет доступа к остальным базам. Под root заходили, смотрели `mysql -uroot` ?

Comment: Я под рутом сижу. Он все видит, потому должен был видеть все базы. Команду -uroot тоже использовал, естественно. Команда вываливает 1064 ошибку и пишет: You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual... и т.д.

Comment: Либо под разными пользователями коннектитесь, либо на разные mysql хосты. На денвере свой mysql? может используется не стандартный порт? Я просто с denwer не работал. Пусть denwer спецы подскажут)

Comment: в системе один пользователь - root. Идет стандартная сборка денвера. mysql тоже один из той стандартной сборки денвера. Порт 8648, который дефолтный от денвера, свободный. Порты тут не при чем, раз  базы выводит, но фрагментарно как-то. Потому действительно жду спецов от денверчан), они должны прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: Если не сложно выполните в консоли mysql запрос SELECT CURRENT_USER(); что он выводит?

Answer (score 1):

Входите в MySQL из консоли при помощи команды: mysql -uroot. Далее show databases.

Comment: Абстрактное понятие "входите в mysql"). Я написал, что через переменные среды windows прописал там запуск mysql через обычную cmd. Потому когда выполняю запуск cmd, затем пишу mysql, а затем пишу -uroot, то выдает ошибку: Error 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-uroot' at line 1. Вот что пишет мне консоль...

Comment: @IntegralAL это "-p8648 -uroot" указывать нужно при подключении к  mysql, а не после.

Comment: В любом случае, проблема такая же. Две базы видны, а из оболочки phpmyadmin 10 баз. Вопрос 10 - 2 = 8. Где еще восемь баз)?